Accidentally mounted a virtual shared folder on ~ and cannot access my normal user's home
Windows host, ubuntu virtualbox. I created a shared folder between the two and accidentally mounted it to ~ with the command
sudo mount -t vboxsf vbox ~/
I tried sudo umount ~/ but got complaints the device was busy.
I tried rebooting the system, but when it booted back in, it seems to have created a default home for my user. I have months of tireless work stuck somewhere I cannot reach, as well as .ssh keys for vpns and vpc machines I must regain.
Please advise!
It was a default ubuntu install, so no distinct /home partition, so I can't see anything through fstab to remount.

Is there actually something else mounted there after reboot? What does findmnt -T ~/ say? If you mounted it with a one-off mount command (rather than adding it to /etc/fstab for example) then the only way I can imagine it persisting after restarting the VM is if you checked the automount option in the VirtualBox shared folder settings.

@steeldriver and @carefulnow were correct - I booted in to recovery mode as root and everything was there, which lead me to the same realisation - automount was remounting each time - additionally, ubuntu was setting up default folders (Desktop, Downloads, etc.) in the shared folder, making it look like a new user's home.
The solution was to disable automount in virtualbox on the host OS.

When you setup the original share in VirtualBox, you would have done it via the GUI:
VirtualBox Share host fodler
Try to reverse the share by removing the share in VirtualBox. If it doesn't exist to share then it should fail to map it and you should be able to see your home folder.

Hi and welcome to the site. We prefer answers to be a bit more explanatory here. What share should be removed? How would it be removed? Is there a command? What command? Is it something you would do from a GUI? What GUI? And how?

Hi, I'm assuming that the user was running the Virtualbox GUI and before you can share a host folder you need to tell VirtualBox about it. I don't run VirtualBox anymore but I recall there is a dialogbox where these are defined. The user should know where this is because they would have needed to set it up before it could be shared.

OK, but that's the sort of detail that really should be in the answer. As it stands, your answer is more of a comment and is likely to be deleted. It'd be great if you could just flesh it out a bit, perhaps add a screenshot of the relevant setting etc.
